# Прилагательное от "подалирий"?

Tags: прилагательные

Как правильно образовать? Подалирьный?

Comment: Это вообще о бабочках?

Comment: @grizzly, да, о расцветке крыльев бабочек

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если это текст научный, лучше отказаться от применения прилагательного, употребив несогласованное определение типа цвет подалирия.

Если это разговорный стиль, возможен такой вариант, как на одном из форумов:"А лето действительно махаоновое. И даже подалириевое.  Не говоря уже о том, что богомоловое". Он воспринимается как окказионализм (авторский неологизм).

Вот ещё пример употребления на биологическом форуме, здесь слово взято в  кавычки. Видимо, такое прилагательное общепринятым не является:

Вы согласны, что "подалириевая" модель на коре дуба - крайне заметна?
http://orthodoxy.cafe/index.php?topic=649865.700

Answer (score 0):

> Подалирьный?

Один из худших вариантов, я полагаю. Я посмотрел пару десятков существительных на **-ий**. Химики обычно образуют прилагательное с помощью **-иевый**: аллюминиевый, родиевый и т.п.

Единственное найденное слово не химического значения, от которого образовано прилагательное, — герундий (прилагательное **герундиальный**, употребляется относительно часто). Замечено несколько попыток образовать прилагательное от **жребий**: жребийный, жребиевый (в словаре Лопатина все эти слова отсутствуют).

Upd. Нет, удалил советы. Оставлю один: советую отказаться от заведомо неуклюжего словообразования.